# How to ensure a UIView has loaded?

Tags: ios, uikit

This may sound silly, but read on...

I want to set the text of a `UILabel` from outside of a `UIViewController` that is instantiated by a storyboard. I need to make sure that the label property of the view controller is set when I set its text otherwise the label's text won't be set(because it won't be loaded yet to receive a text value).

Here's my current solution:

```
// Show pin entry
if (!self.pinViewController) {
    // Load pin view controller
    self.pinViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pinScreen"];
    self.pinViewController.delegate = self;
    if (!self.pinViewController.view) {
        // Wait for pin screen to fully load
    }
    [self.pinViewController setMessageText:@"Set a pin for this device"];
}
```

Initially I had a `while` loop that looped until the value of `view` was not `nil`, But it seems the very act of checking the view loads it(as mentioned here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW37)

I tried using the `isViewLoaded` method with no success. It just looped forever.

I've gone forward with the above code as my current solution, but it feels wrong.

**Is there a better way ensure a `UIView` has loaded?**

Comment: if you doing it correctly, `viewController.view` will never be `nil` because the getter will create the view if it is not created yet

Answer (score 2):

I want to propose an alternative way where you don't have to rely on the availability of the view.
If you need to wait for the view to load before you can call other methods on your viewController you break encapsulation, because the viewController that calls your PinViewController has to know about the inner workings of your PinViewController. That's usually not a good idea.

But you could save objects like NSStrings in the PinViewController instance, and when the view of the PinViewController will appear you set its views according to the properties you have set before.
If you need to change the text of an label from outside your viewController you can also create a custom setter that sets the label.text for you.

Your .h

```
@interface PinViewController : UIViewController
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *messageText;
// ...
@end
```

And your .m

```
@implementation PinViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.messageLabel.text = self.messageText;
}

// optional, if you want to change the message text from another viewController:
- (void)setMessageText:(NSString *)messageText {
    _messageText = messageText;
    self.messageLabel.text = messageText;
}

// ...

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` should solve this I guess.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I would rather see you change your logic and do it the way that @MatthiasBauch shows in his answer.  However, to answer your actual question, you can simply set a view property in order to force it to load:

```
self.pinViewController.view.hidden = NO;
```